# Update or Delete SharePoint List from Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, sharepoint-2010

I have successfully been able to create a new `list` on my `SharePoint` site using the `DoCmd`.`TransferDatabase` method. However, I run into issues if the list name already exists. I could use a unique name every time I create a list, but I'd prefer to either update the current `SharePoint` list or delete and then re-add the list using `TransferDatabase`. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945297/what-is-the-difference-between-docmd-deleteobject-actable-vs-drop-table) that describes how to delete tables in `Access`, but I don't see how it can apply to deleting `SharePoint` lists.

I am using **Access 2010** and **SharePoint 2010**.

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with very much the same issue and just tried

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    CurrentDb().TableDefs.Delete CurrentDb().TableDefs("[a]").Name
    CurrentDb().TableDefs.Delete CurrentDb().TableDefs("[UserInfo]").Name
End Sub
```

And it does remove the tables. Only the update of the panel on the left seems to need a bit of clicking before the disconnect appears