# Drop All Tables Except One in MS Access (2007-2013)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to delete all tables except for one in Access. This is done locally, so there are no linked tables and no relationships. The table I am to keep is 'Log' (historical record).

I three tables and two import-error tables I aim to drop. This is a monthly process and the import error tables may be named differently each month, so a few daisy-chained DROP TABLE "Table1_ImportErrors" queries won't necessarily work.

The code [here](https://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/msoffice/creating-a-drop-down-parameter-in-access-2010-2.html) doesn't seem to apply since I can only really name the table I want to keep (this designates tables to drop by name - I won't have that in the case of import errors).

What I currently have is:

-dbo.Table1

-dbo.Table2

-dbo.Table3

-dbo.T2Sheetname_ImportErrors

-dbo.T3Sheetname_ImportErrors

-dbo.Log

-9 Queries

-4 Macros

-2 Modules

I want to keep all queries, macros, modules, and dbo.Log.

I'm just learning VBA, but unclear on what to do here. Open to using a query here as well or other approaches. I appreciate any input and am glad to answer any questions.

EDIT: The following worked for me.

```
Private Sub
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table1"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table2"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table3"

Dim tdf as TableDef
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Right(tdf.Name, 12) = "ImportErrors" Then
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.Name
        End If
    Next tdf
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the results of googling some phrases like "msaccess for all tables"  and "msaccess vba delete table".  Use Google, it is your friend.

Depending of what the msgbox sez, you may need to filter on "dbo.Log" or on "Log".

```
'From  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555174/how-to-loop-through-all-tables-in-an-ms-access-db 

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        ' ignore system and temporary tables
        If Not (tdf.name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.name Like "~*") Then
            If tdf.name <> "Log" Then
            MsgBox("deleting " & tdf.name)
            '  from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945297/what-is-the-difference-between-docmd-deleteobject-actable-vs-drop-table
            'DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.name
        End If
        End If
    Next
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried Googling around for this and I have found this answer as well. As implemented here, the code does not run properly. It gives me notification messages in a dialog box (the MsgBox) for a number of items, but does not actually delete any of them. I do not know enough to parse out what isn't working.

I do not receive any error messages, just notifications from the MsgBox.

Comment: @TJ15 Yes, it gives you messages for verification testing.  I want you to be sure that the right tables are found and selected for deletion, BEFORE you actually run it for real.  When you are ready, then change MsgBox to Debug.Print  and remove the comment mark from the  'DoCmd  line to actually do the delete.